# Suitable bridge projects for new EVM chain

Tags: bridge

I am working on developing a bridge between my custom EVM chain and other chains such as Ethereum and BSC. Is anyone aware of any suitable existing projects on git hub that I can base my project on?
I have found https://github.com/omni/tokenbridge are there any more suitable alternatives?